# $.Get() method with authentication 401 response

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax get method, it needs credentials to work.
I have the credenntials to access the API, i don't know how to pass the credentials through the get method:

```
$.get(url, function (response) {
  $.each(JSON.parse(response).canchas, function (key, bucket) {
  }
}
```

thanks!

edit:

```
$.ajax({

        url: "https://tes.r/links/" + id + "/buckets",
        data: {username: "backoffice", password: "111111"},
        dataType: "JSON",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (response)
        {
            $("#ul_list_view").empty();
            $.each(response.buckets, function (key, bucket) {

                $("#ul_list_view").append('<li><a href="#" class="ver_detalle" data-bucket_id="' + bucket.id + '"><h2>' + bucket.dayOfWeek + '</h2><p>' + bucket.timeOfDay + '</p></a></li>');
            });
            $("#ul_list_view").listview("refresh");
        },

       error: function (response)
            {

                $("#div_resultado2").addClass("error");
                $("#div_resultado2").html(response.responseText);
            }
    });
```

Still returning 401, username and password is correct

Comment: Here, you dropped this ~ `)`

Comment: You would modify the `url` variable to include the API.

Comment: So, noticed you're still not using the `username` and `password` fields. How does the API at `tes.r` specify you supply credentials?

Comment: shouldn't it be in data:{username:xxx,password:xxxx}??

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean the API uses HTTP Basic authentication, use `$.ajax` instead and pass the `username` and `password` properties ~ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax(url, {
  username: 'backoffice',
  password: '111111',
  dataType: 'json' // no need for JSON.parse if you tell jQuery the response type
}).done(response => {
  $.each(response.canchas, (key, bucket) => {
    // etc
  })
})
```